# How do I get the taxonomy term name of the current taxonomy term page.tpl.php?

Tags: 7, theming, taxonomy-terms

Im on d7. Im trying to get the taxonomy term name of the the taxonomy page that I am on. Since Im not on a "node" page, I can't get it by the $node->tid. What should I do?
Thanks.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try..

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--taxonomy--taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_term_load/7

```
$term = taxonomy_term_load(arg(2));
$title = $term->name;
```

arg(2) should return the tid of the taxonomy page (taxonomy/term/tid).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I tried your method, but I'm getting this error `Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in include() (line 79 of {my site}/templates/page.tpl.php)` and its not working. :(

Comment: What does `print_r(arg())` show?

Comment: Array ( [0] => taxonomy [1] => term [2] => 1920 )

Comment: figured it out, Ill explain below

Answer (score 6):

I figured it out, heres what I did:

```
<?php
$termid = arg(2);
$term = taxonomy_term_load($termid);
$title = $term->name;
?>
```

Thank you @Kevin for your help.

Comment: +1 for saving taxonomy-term-id is separate variable. It follows KISS principle(atleast from my point-of-view).

Comment: Works perfectly, took me a little while to find a correct answer so thank you.

Answer (score -4):

Instead of using taxonomy_term_load() which is not working well every time, you can call:

```
function get_tag_name($tid) {
    $query = db_select('taxonomy_term_data', 't');
    $query
            ->condition('t.tid', $tid, '=')
            ->fields('t', array('tid', 'name'));
    $result = $query->execute();

    foreach ($result as $row) {
        return $row->name;
    }
}
```